# Is there a good area to farm Hag's Skin?

Tags: titan-quest, titan-quest-anniversary-edition

I need Hag's Skin to craft an artifact.
I tried to farm it throughout in Act 2 by killing Hags and Crones and such. But they seem to appear only very sporadically.
Even in areas where they do occur, there never seems to be more than 2 or 3 packs of a handful of monsters each.

Is there any area where they appear more often or in bigger groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Titan Queust wiki page for Hag's Skin](http://titanquest.wikia.com/wiki/Hag%27s_Skin) lists which enemies drop Hag's Skin and has a list of best places to farm it.

It is dropped by:

1. Desert Crone
2. Desert Hag
3. Desert Witch
4. Sandwing - Crone
5. Sandwing - Hag
6. Sandwing - Witch
7. Bloodwing - Crone
8. Bloodwing - Hag

It suggests these farming locations:

- 2.1 Rhakotis Slums (1, 2)
- 2.1 Lookout Cave (2)
- 2.1 Hathor Basin (1, 2)
- 2.1 Wadjet Canyons (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
- 2.2 Nile Floodplain (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
- 2.2 The Lower Nile (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
- 2.3 Memphis Outskirts (1, 2, 4, 5, 7)
- 2.3 Outer Giza (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7)
- 2.3 Sobek Plateau (1, 3, 4, 5)
- 2.3 Canyon of Isis (4, 5, 6, 7)
- 2.3 The Upper Nile (4, 5, 6, 7)
- 2.5 Fayum Desert (1, 3, 4, 5, 7)
- 2.6 Highland Pass (4, 5, 7, 8)

Comment: Unfortunately all listed areas seem to have the problem I described: They contain at most 2 small packs of those monsters. But I think I found a good farming path, which I'll describe in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer Paul gave outlines all areas containing monster with a chance to drop Hag's Skin. Unfortunately all of those areas seem to have 2 small packs at most.

However, I think I found a good way to farm Hag's Skin regardless:
Start from the Waypoint in the Fayum Oasis and head for the gate to the right. There often is a pack just outside, if it's birds instead, exit and try again. Then head west to the exit of the area leading to Canyon of Isis, with any luck you'll pass another pack on the way.
In the canyon there should be another pack located at the westernmost edge.
Now go south to the Sobek Plateau. At the western edge there will be Hero Monster named Sandqueen Masika, which seems to have higher chance to drop Hag's Skin than usual.

Exit the game and repeat until satisfied.

(Not sure if Sandqueen Masika was added in the Anniversary edition or already present in Immortal Throne).